dmesg log being flooded by audit, can I somehow prevent it?
I'm torrenting with Transmission GTK. My dmesg log is being flooded by audit, and without knowing what good it is for, I do not even care much, I cannot use dmesg for other purposes. It floods so fast I am even unable to make text selection... Therefore let me excuse for this image:

I am on Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon, so this question does not really answer my need.

First few observations. You are using Transmission GTK with App Armor. And it is AppArmor that is generating those messages. And by default it will go to dmesg. Cant change that.
Secondly based on the screenshot that has been provided it seems that the auditd service that is running has not been configured with apparmour functionality. That is why you are getting all the numerical values in name and other fields. And that is leading to an eye sore for you. Please refer to this link for more information. It is for a distro other than Mint but it will be applicable for your case too. To fix this issue please raise a discussion in the Mint support Forum with the relevant details and ask them how to configure auditd service with the apparmour functionality. Attach the same screenshot and ask them that you want to replace the numeric values with relevant text values.
Thirdly and finally the question link that you have provided has some good suggestions. Please see if those work.
Now I am assuming that you do not want to disable auditd service. And if you are thinking of doing that then please do not do it. You can explore the option of running Transmission GTK without App Armor but it will reduce your safety and security online.
Finally there might be a way to stop the audit messages from App Armor when it runs Transmission GTK. This is not full proof but might work. Run one of the following commands. The 2nd command is preferred.
auditctl -A exclude,never -F pid=20279

OR
auditctl -A exclude,never -F path=Replace_This_With_Absolute_Path_To_TransmissionGTK

Replace the 20279 with the process ID of the Transmission GTK process. If you are using the second command give the absolute path of Transmission GTK.
Strongly urge you to use the second command. If it does not work then use the first.
Explanation of the command

-A = This will add a rule at the beginning of existing rules.
exclude = filter out those events that you do not want to see
never = No audit records will be generated
-F = Build a rule. There can be upto 64 different rules chained. One after the other.
pid = Filter the rule based on the PID. This is dangerous because the
Process ID will change on reboot or when Transmission GTK will shut
down.
20279 = This value I took from the screenshot that you had attached.
This has to be replaced with the actual Process ID of Transmission GTK.
path = Filter the rule based on the absolute path.


More details are given in the manual page of auditd. Please go through it. Will help you.
Once you have done your investigation and you do not need to filter the audit messages from Transmission GTK give the following command to delete the rule
auditctl -d exclude,never -F pid=20279

OR
auditctl -d exclude,never -F path=Replace_This_With_Absolute_Path_To_TransmissionGTK

Based on which rule you had implemented.
Replace 20279 and Replace_This_With_Absolute_Path_To_TransmissionGTK with the relevant values.

Editor's Notes:

I had to modify the command according to man page to (and it appears to work now after reboot):
# auditctl -a exclude,never -F exe=/usr/bin/transmission-gtk


Though, this rule appears not to survive reboot.

I should have stated, it told me at first, I don't have auditd installed. So, I naturally installed it. What did not come to my mind it solve the issue itself, maybe it does because after another reboot, I don't see any Transmission GTK related messages in dmesg!


